# Unable to read or set scrollLeft for body

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/4sBep/2/ - that has a draggable beige box.  When you right-click the box a red box is created to the right of it. If the beige box is too close to the right edge, so that the complete red box is not visible, a scroll bar appears for the body element.

The problem is I'm not able to read the scrollLeft value for body after creating the red box (third line from the bottom) to see the how much of the red box is not showing, and I'm not able to set the body scroll value to show more of the red box (last line).

Does anyone see the problem?
Thanks

```
 $('#box').draggable();
    $('#box').contextmenu(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var doc_offset;
        boxWidth = $('#box').width();

        doc_offset = $(this).offset();
        doc_offset.left = doc_offset.left +  boxWidth + 20;
        $('<div>').css({width:"150px", 
                        height:"150px",
                        'background-color':'red',
                        position : 'absolute'
                       })
                 .offset(doc_offset)
                  .appendTo('body');  

        var scroll_left = $('body').scrollLeft();
        $('#scrollStatus').html("Scroll left is " + scroll_left);
        $('body').scrollLeft(150);

     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the `scrollLeft()` correctly. The problem is that when you are setting it, you are just asking it to scroll 150 instead of adding 150 to the current scroll. You should be doing

```
$('body').scrollLeft(scroll_left + doc_offset.left);
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4sBep/3/) This will set the body scroll to show entire red box.

Comment: Yes, that works in Chrome but Firefox doesn't scroll automatically for me to show the red box.  Also, in both Chrome and Firefox the scrollLeft read seems to always come back 0, before and after we've set the scroll.  The jsfiddle here reads and shows the scrollLeft value before and after we set it.

Comment: Sorry.  The link to the jsfiddle didn't go in above. It's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/MkSJH/1/)